# adf test summary may be unreliable

Tags: r, time-series

```
#Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test for Life Expectancy
adf_LE_none <- ur.df(norway$mortality,type=c("none"),lags=1,
+                      selectlags=c("AIC"))
Warning messages:
1: In summary.lm(result) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
2: In summary.lm(result) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

I am trying to do adf test for a time-series model but getting that warning message? Is it important or need to be solved?